# UINavigationBar title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to use a UILabel to replace the title at the UINavigationBar, the code is as follows:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
    [bar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    UILabel * nav_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 2, 220, 25)];
    nav_title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
    nav_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nav_title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    nav_title.text = title;
    nav_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [bar addSubview:nav_title];
    [nav_title release];
```

The problem is that, how do I remove the original title of the bar? I didn't declare any self.title = @"title", but it always shows it there:

[image]

If I do self.title = nil, then everything is gone... How do eliminate this mysterious title from the navbar and just use the UILabel I created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do self.title = @""?

EDIT: Try this?

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UILabel * nav_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 2, 220, 25)];
nav_title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
nav_title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
nav_title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
nav_title.text = title;
self.title = @"";
nav_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[bar addSubview:nav_title];
[nav_title release];
```

Comment: that is because you set nav_title.text = title, and then set title = @""

Comment: so what I did is add the UILabel as a subview then do self.title = @"" and then inside viewWillDisapper I remove the label from the superView.. Is there any beter way than this?

Comment: @shabzco, is 220x25 is the default label size for navigation bar ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.navigationItem.titleView = nav_title;` instead of adding your label as a subview.

Comment: the issue is that can you can't adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth with that.
Initially I was using that, but I was disturbed by the .... when the text is long

Comment: Maybe wrap the label in an ordinary UIView, let the outer view do the autoresizing and have the inner label resize its font.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [label setText:self.title];
  label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
  label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
  label.numberOfLines=0;
  [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:label];
  [label release];

Hope this will help u..!
```