# How do I change UINavigationBar title label size?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

One I decide to make custom navigation bar design the right way. My navigation bar's title should be typed with custom font "Din Condensed" with size 23. So I wrote this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_background.png"]
                                 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                          UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                          UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"PFDinTextCondPro-Bold" size:23]
}];
```

But looks like title label can't fit text with this font:

[image: title label size]

How can I change size of UINavigationBar title using appearance API? I want to avoid using custom titleView.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to change its font size. At least not as far as I know. The navigation bar will automatically resize the default title label's font size to fit either in portrait or landscape orientation.

Therefore you need a custom title view. But it's pretty simple; just need to set the navigation item's `titleView` to your label.

Example with multiple lines: [UINavigationBar multi-line title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422383/uinavigationbar-multi-line-title)

Example with single line but different font: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171426/894671

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setTitlePositionAdjustment` to fix this problem? If this does not work I think the best way is for you to have a `UILabel` customized with the font you want and use it as `titleView` (custom view) attribute of navigation bar.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It doesn't help. Looks like there is no other way than custom view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set title font in the storyboard.

1. Inspect UINavigationController
2. Open its UINavigationBar
3. Set title font under title text attributes.

Now it shouldn't cut your title label.