# Title text in navigation bar not truncating immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a navigation bar with title that can be changed. The title strings are very long and are not truncated unless I move off this page and come back again.

So after the initial title change it will look like this:
[image: Immediately after changing title]

Then after segueing to another page and going back it will switch back to what everyone would expect:
[image: After segueing out and coming back]

I want to be able to have this text truncation occur immediately after the text has been updated

The problem is I have no idea what is causing this issue or where it is happening, thus do not know what code to include in my question.. I was guessing something like `navigationItem.titleView` to have an "update contents" but cannot find anything that fixes this problem.

Comment: Check below link. May be it ill solve your issue. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15480235/1850983](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15480235/1850983)

Answer (score 0):

All view controllers has a property called "title", try to put your string like this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = "YourString";
}
```

Or in Swift code...

```
func viewDidLoad {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.title = "YourString"
}
```